# Multiple jsp pages's request using single servlet

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am creating admin page. Where i have mainly three pages, For example here 1.) Show All itmes. 2.) Add new Item 3.) Edit Item. Now i want only single servlet for all three pages. So how can servlet understand which page request and how can particular method or conditions will be apply on that page. I could't find any relevant answer for this. I got the answer that multiple actions from pages handling into single servlet. But i have three different jsp pages. So can any one help me for this. Please give me some suggestion or link so i can implement on my project. I am not showing whole code here, because of lengthy coding. I just some logic about it. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in jsp

```
<%
String servletParam = "add" or "edit" or "show";
request.setParameter(servletParam,servletParam)
%>
```

in your servlet

```
String servletParam = request.getParameter("servletParam");
if(servletParam.equals("add"))
{
// add code here
}
if(servletParam.equals("edit"))
{
// edit code here
}
if(servletParam.equals("show"))
{
// show code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer@HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri' but i couldn't find Request.setParameter(servletParam,servletParam) in jsp. Is thi request.setAttribute or any other method?

Comment: yes this is request.setParameter or you can use request.setAttribute or if you are using session then use session.setAtribute

Comment: I have checked both of this but its not working. So thanks for the answer but if you any other suggestion about it then kindly give it. @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri'

Comment: 1.jsp{<%
String servletParam = "add";
request.setAttribute("servletParam",servletParam);<htm></html>
%>}
2.jsp{<%
String servletParam = "edit";
request.setAttribute("servletParam",servletParam);<htm></html>
%>}
3.jsp
{<%
String servletParam = "show";
request.setAttribute("servletParam",servletParam);<htm></html>
%>}

Now this three jsp calling single servlet which named as JspControlling
{String servletParam = request.getParameter("servletParam");
if(servletParam=="add")
{
out.write("add");}
if(servletParam=="edit")
{
out.write("edit");
}
if(servletParam=="show")
{
out.write("show");
}}

Comment: Above code is temporary code what i have tried. @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri'